# Redirect Url After Form Submission

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a basic form that allows a user to create an `Employee`. Once the user selects the `submit` button, the page should be `redirected` to a summary page. This summary page needs to show the details that were added on the `Employee` form.

For example, I have a form that looks like this:

[image]

Once the user selects `Submit`, it should then redirect the user to the following page:

[image]

> The issue that I'm running into is getting that **redirect url.** My url looks something like: http://www.localhost.com/Employee/1234/ The `1234` represents the `Employee` id. How can I pull that `Employee Id`?

**My Current HTML**

```
<button type="submit" name="saveButton" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

> Please note that I am using .NET, so am open to using `Razor Syntax.`

**Update on Story**

After reading all of your comments, I went and dug deeper into my problem. This is what I found.

There is a `RouteConfig.cs` file with the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "ListEmployee",
  url: "Employee/{employeeId}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "List"},
  constraints: new {employeeId = "\\d+"}
)
```

Because I have this route, I decided to modify this controller method to utilize it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEmployee(ViewModel<EmployeeModel> model)
{
  // logic here

  return RedirectToAction("ListEmployee", new { employeeId = model.Body.Employee.Id, fromEmployeeProject = true });
}
```

> **Issue:** This completely crashes. Stating: `No route in the route table matches the supplied values.` Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: After the form submission, my code is going to need to find the `EmployeeId` that gets assigned to that user. For example, after submission, my `URL` will look something like this: `http://www.localhost.com/Employee/1234`

Comment: do you need the employee id so that you can display the newly added `Employee` object in the "summary" page?

Comment: Exactly. I need that `Employee Id` so that I can view the summary for that specific `Employee`

Comment: How are you saving the employee record? Is the `EmployeeId` attribute being generated by the server and/or database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework (EF), it follows up each `INSERT` statement with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` when auto-generated ids are used.

> SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28v=sql.110%29.aspx))

As such, if your `Employee` ID is an auto-generated column in the database, you should be able to get the ID right after saving your changes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Employee employee)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        // add the employee object
        context.Employees.Add(employee);
        // save changes
        context.SaveChanges();
        // the id will be available here
        int employeeId = employee.Id;   
        // ..so perform your Redirect to the appropriate action, _
        // and pass employee.Id as a parameter to the action       
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee", new { id = employeeId });            
    }
}
```

Obviously you haven't provided us with your controller and action names so make sure that you replace them  with the appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks @trashr0x, I dug deeper because of your post, but ended up running into another error. I've updated my story to reflect that error. Any ideas?

Comment: You're passing a route name to `RedirectToAction`, try `RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee", //...)` (or whatever your controllers and actions are named)

Comment: Ended up using something very similar to your `return` statement. The `new {....}` was especially helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One of the most common way of doing it is to return different View from your Action that you call from Employee Form. For instance let say your Employee Forms calls EmployeeController->Add(Employee employee) action

Inside of your Employee Action you will have something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Employee employee)
{
    // process request and create new employee in repository

    return View("Summary");
}
```

Another way of doing it is to call RedirectToAction(), this is similar to Response.Redirect() in ASP.NET WebForms.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Employee employee)
{
    // process request and create new employee in repository

    return RedirectToAction("Summary");
}
```

You can allso call Redirect method. This will cause the browser to receive 302 error and redirect to your controller/action specified

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Employee employee)
{
    // process request and create new employee in repository

    return Redirect("YourController/Summary");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would this approach allow me to pull the `Employee Id`?

Comment: Yes, you need to properly construct your Route so you can get Employee Id, please take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx or this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Thanks @Vlad Bezden, I went and looked deeper because of your post and now have a new problem. I've updated my story to reflect the issue.

Comment: Do you even get to AddEmployee action? Based on your router configuration I doubt. Could you please let me know if you get inside of your action. Also could you please provide url that you get when you submit your form. You can get url from your browser dev tool or using tools like Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

To get the id you can, in your view, add an input type hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="[value]" />
```

in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult [ActionName] (int id)
{
.....
employeeRepository.Save(employee);
return RedirectToAction("Summary", new {id});
}
```

and in your action Summary:

```
public ActionResult Summary(int id)
{
.....
}
```