# Retrieve Scope_Identity using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity after creating new account

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a working solution using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity allowing for registration and login.

Upon successful registration, how do I get the scope_identity when the record is inserted in the database table? I do not see any stored procedures that I can modify to retrieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to retrieve the property values of the newly-registered user object? is this Web Forms or MVC?

Comment: Precisely. Specifically the auto-generated ID I have setup on the table. This is web forms.

Comment: are you using EF? if so see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32653020/4302070)

Comment: Many thanks. I have it figured out now.